# How to modify selectWithKeyChar()'s function in JComboBox.java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, combobox

I have a combo box that contains items that start with special characters (ie. À).

Currently, when using the combo box, if you press a key (ie. "a"), it selects an item that starts with the same first letter - but it wouldn't select the one that starts with the special character..

Is there a way to modify the method selectWithKeyChar() in JComboBox.java to ignore the special characters and and treat it like a regular character?

Solutions I have thought of but don't know how to implement:

1) Passing in a temporary combo box model to selectWithKeyChar() that doesn't include the accents. If this is possible, how do you pass in the model to selectWithKeyChar()?

2) Overriding the selectWithKeyChar() method?

3) Making a custom method. In this case, how would you make it run instead of the one that already exists in JComboBox.java?

Here is a minimal example of my setup:

- create a new project
- create a new file that has a JPanel form file type
- add a combo box with the following items: "Àpplebee", "Test", "Able"
- call the JPanel in the main:

  > ```
  >    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
  >         @Override
  >         public void run(){
  >             JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  >             frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  >             frame.getContentPane().add(new B());
  >             frame.pack();
  >             frame.setVisible(true);
  >         }
  >     });
  > ```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Passing in a temporary combo box model to selectWithKeyChar() that
>   doesn't include the accents. If this is possible, how do you pass in
>   the model to selectWithKeyChar()?
>
> 2) Overriding the selectWithKeyChar() method?
>
> 3) Making a custom method. In this case, how would you make it run
>   instead of the one that already exists in JComboBox.java?

All of this are possible, You can create a `temp` **ComoBoxModel** and you `extends` JComboBox to override `selectWithKeyCharacter` on your `CustomComboBox`. Here is the sample of a code:

**CustomComboBox.java**

```
public class CustomComboBox extends JComboBox<String>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public CustomComboBox(String[] items) {
    super(items);
}

@Override
public boolean selectWithKeyChar(char keyChar) {
    int index;

    ComboBoxModel<String> tempModel = getModel(); // Put the model on temp variable for saving it for later use.

    String[] itemsArr = new String[getModel().getSize()];
    for(int i = 0; i < getModel().getSize(); i++) {
        // This will normalizes the Strings
        String normalize = Normalizer.normalize(getModel().getElementAt(i), Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
        normalize = normalize.replaceAll("\\p{M}", "");
        itemsArr[i] = normalize;
    }

    if ( keySelectionManager == null )
        keySelectionManager = createDefaultKeySelectionManager();

    setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(itemsArr)); // Set the Temporary items to be checked.
    index = keySelectionManager.selectionForKey(keyChar,getModel());
    setModel(tempModel); // Set back the original items.

    System.out.println(index);
    if ( index != -1 ) {
        setSelectedIndex(index);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

If you will test it, even if you enter a normal char 'a', it will select the element in JComboBox with accent or with non-accent.

**TestMain.java**

```
public class TestMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] lists = {"ápa","Zabra","Prime"};
    CustomComboBox combo = new CustomComboBox(lists);
    System.out.println(combo.selectWithKeyChar('A'));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    combo.setSize(70, 30);
    combo.setLocation(100, 100);
    frame.add(combo);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it doesn't work properly if there's more than one item with the same first letter. Why does it keep closing the combobox every time you press a button? Thank you for responding